# Checkboxes not working on click in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

So ,I am trying to make some checkboxes in a pop up filter menu on click of a button.
Below here is the common code for the pop up menu

```
const MenuPop = ({onClose , visible, isLoading,item,values}) => {
  const handleClose = (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault()
    if(e.target.id==='parent'){
      onClose()
    }
  }
  if(!visible)
    return null;

    return (
    <div 
    id="parent" 
    className={`${values} fixed z-[100] inset-0 bg-[black] bg-opacity-50`}
    onClick={handleClose}
    >
      {item}

    </div>
  )
}
```

here are the different variables that I have used as props using a React hook

```
const useCommonItems = () => {
    const [visible, setvisible] = useState(false)
    const handleClose =()=>{
      setvisible(false)
    }
    return {
        visible,
        setvisible,
        handleClose
    }
}
```

here is my page where I have a button the opens the pop up menu on the click of a button

```
const App=()=>{
const {visible,setvisible,handleClose}=useCommonItems();//react hook to get commonly used variables
return (
<>
   <button onClick={e=>{
   e.preventDefault();
   //making the visible = true
   setvisible(true)
   }>Click Me </button>
   <MenuPop visible={visible} onClose={handleClose} values="flex justify-center items- 
    center" item={<Filter/>} />
<>
);}
```

here is the  component that opens up as soon as the button "Click Me" above is click

```
const Filter = () => {
  const PriceArray = ["100", "300", "1000", "2000"];
  const [priceVariable, setPriceVariable] = useState(0);
  console.log(priceVariable)
  const headingClass = "text-[20px] text-blue-600 font-semibold";
  const inputClass =
    "mr-[15px] border-[2px] font-[300] w-4 h-4 text-blue-600 bg-gray-100 border-gray-300 rounded focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:ring-blue-600 dark:ring-offset-gray-800 focus:ring-2 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 accent-blue-600 ";
  const parentCaseClass = "border-b-[2px] border-blue-600 mb-[20px] pb-[20px]";
  return (
    <div className="bg-[white] 450:w-[450px] w-[100%] p-[20px] rounded-[20px] grid grid-flow-row grid-cols-1 450:grid-cols-2">
      <div className={`Price ${parentCaseClass} `}>
        <p className={`${headingClass}`}>Price</p>
        {PriceArray.map((item, id) => (
          <div className="" key={id}>
            <input type="checkbox" value={item} id={name} name={item} className={inputClass} />
            <label htmlFor={item}>{item}</label>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>  
    </div>
  );
};
```

So why are the checkboxes not working on clicking them?Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A checkbox should have a `checked` attribute which holds a boolean value. More information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox).

What you can do is create a checkbox component like this:

```
const Checkbox = ({ checked, onChange, id, className }) => {
  return (
    <input
      id={id}
      className={className}
      checked={checked}
      type="checkbox"
      onChange={onChange}
    />
 );
};
```

Use it like this:

```
// import or create a constant called SOME_CHECKBOX_NAME_CONSTANT
// that holds the label names

const Component = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    isSomeUseCaseData: false,
  });

  const onChangeCheckbox = (event) => {
    setData({ isSomeUseCaseData: event.target.checked });
  };

  return (
    <div className="some-form-name">
      {Object.keys(data).map((item) => (
        <Checkbox
          key={item}
          id={`${item}-id`}
          checked={data[item]}
          onChange={onChangeCheckbox}
          className="some-class-name"
        >
         <span>{SOME_CHECKBOX_NAME_CONSTANT[item]}</span>
       </Checkbox>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Now you have a controlled checkbox. Your `Filter` component might look like this:

```
const Filter = () => {
  const PriceArray = ['100', '300', '1000', '2000'];
  const [priceVariable, setPriceVariable] = useState(0);

  const [data, setData] = useState({});

  const headingClass = 'text-[20px] text-blue-600 font-semibold';
  const inputClass = 'mr-[15px] border-[2px] font-[300] w-4 h-4 text-blue-600 bg-gray-100 border-gray-300 rounded focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:ring-blue-600 dark:ring-offset-gray-800 focus:ring-2 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 accent-blue-600 ';
  const parentCaseClass = 'border-b-[2px] border-blue-600 mb-[20px] pb-[20px]';

  return (
    <div className="450:w-[450px] 450:grid-cols-2 grid w-[100%] grid-flow-row grid-cols-1 rounded-[20px] bg-[white] p-[20px]">
      <div className={`Price ${parentCaseClass} `}>
        <p className={`${headingClass}`}>Price</p>
          {PriceArray.map((item, id) => (
            <div
              className=""
              key={id}
            >
             <Checkbox
               value={item}
               id={name}
               name={name}
               className={inputClass}
               checked={data[item] || false}
               onChange={(e) => {
                 setData(() => ({ ...data, [item]: e.target.checked }));
               }}
             />
             <label htmlFor={item}>{item}</label>
           </div>
         ))}
       </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Audience please don't curse me in the comments, I did not have time to refactor [@randeepsarma24](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14120802/randeepsarma24)'s code.